# Delete File and Folder in Android Studio in android Q and R?

Tags: android, android-studio

I take photos and videos with the phone camera in my app. And I also create folder. But sometimes I need to delete or move them. I'm new to android. I'm having problems with Android Q and R. Is there anyone who can help me with the code?
(Note-1: I tried many ways like file.delete() and FileUtils.deleteDirectory() but it didn't work.
Note-2: I can only delete 'hollow folders'.)

Comment: There is nothing special in Q and R to delete files or folders if your app created them. So what is the problem?

Comment: @blackapps Some were not created by my app. can't i delete them?

Comment: No. That will not go unless you request and get 'all files access'. Or use SAF.